# Firebase database: change generated key to custom key + structure

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a chatbot and therefore I want to achieve the following structure in Firebase.

[image]

If someone wants to know what ADHD is I can easily get the data by editing the database ref to `ref('data/disorders/' + disorder + '/' + questionType')`.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to get this structure:

**Problem 1**: Before the questions and answers can be added I want to create a list of the different disorders.

I'm using the `push()` function (`Database.ref('chatbot/disorders').push(disorder)`) but the result is not what I'm looking for.

[image]

**Problem 2**: How can I change the automatic generated key to a disorder name like ADHD or depression?

UPDATE:

So first I want to achieve this structure first:

`{
    "disorders": {
        "ADHD"
        "autisme"
        "depression"
        "..."
    }
}`

and when a question - answer is added:

`{
    "disorders": {
        "ADHD": {
             "what": "ADHD is ...",
             "signs": "The main symptoms of ADHD are ...",
             "types": "There are three different ..."
        }
        "autisme": {
             "what": "Autism ..."
        }
        "..."
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use push when you need to [generate automatically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push) a key for the data you're saving.

If you need to save data having your own key, instead, you can just avoid using it. For example, in your case, you can [use set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write)

```
var disorder = {'description': 'Attention deficit...'};
Database.ref('chatbot/disorders/ADHD').set(disorder);
```

Or you can [use update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)

```
var disorder = {'ADHD':{'description': 'Attention deficit...'}};
Database.ref('chatbot/disorders').update(disorder);
```

For what concerns your "problem 1", I think you should review your database structure. Maybe something like this could work out:

```
{
    "disorders": {
        "ADHD": {
            "description": "Disorder mainly hitting children ...",
            "posts": {
                "autogenerated-key-via-push": {
                    ...
                }...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

In your examples, you're already setting a description. Is it also possible to set a disorder or list of disorders before setting a description? It's because in the cms there is a form to add a name of a disorder and if the disorder is added you can add question and answers (descriptions).

Comment: you mean creating an empty disorders/ADHD node? You can't do it, but if you need to create a placeholder you can create a node with some basic information in it. For example, `Database.ref('chatbot/disorders/ADHD').set({'name':'ADHD'});`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant! Sorry for the weird description :-)

Okey, thanks for the placeholder answer!